# An async/await example that causes a deadlock

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, deadlock, async-await, c#-5.0

I came across some best practices for asynchronous programming using c#'s `async`/`await` keywords (I'm new to c# 5.0).

One of the advices given was the following:

**Stability: Know your synchronization contexts**

... 
Some synchronization contexts are non-reentrant and single-threaded. This means only one unit of work can be executed in the context at a given time. An example of this is the Windows UI thread or the ASP.NET request context.
In these single-threaded synchronization contexts, it’s easy to deadlock yourself. If you spawn off a task from a single-threaded context, then wait for that task in the context, your waiting code may be blocking the background task.

```
public ActionResult ActionAsync()
{
    // DEADLOCK: this blocks on the async task
    var data = GetDataAsync().Result;

    return View(data);
}

private async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    // a very simple async method
    var result = await MyWebService.GetDataAsync();
    return result.ToString();
}
```

If I try to dissect it myself, the main thread spawns to a new one in `MyWebService.GetDataAsync();`, but since the main thread awaits there, it waits on the result in `GetDataAsync().Result`. Meanwhile, say the data is ready. Why doesn't the main thread continue it's continuation logic and returns a string result from `GetDataAsync()` ?

Can someone please explain me why there is a deadlock in the above example?
I'm completely clueless about what the problem is ...

Comment: Are you really sure that GetDataAsync finishes it's stuff? Or it gets stuck causing just lock and not deadlock?

Comment: This is the example that was provided. To my understanding it should finish it's stuff and have a result of some sort ready ...

Comment: Why are you even waiting for the task? You should be awaiting instead because you basically lost all benefits of async model.

Comment: To add to @ToniPetrina's point, even w/o the deadlock problem, `var data = GetDataAsync().Result;` is a line of code that should **never** be done in a context that you should not block (UI or ASP.NET request). **Even if it doesn't deadlock, it is blocking the thread an indeterminate amount of time.**  So basically its a terrible example. [You need to get off of the UI thread before executing code like that, or use `await` there also, as Toni suggests.]

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), Stephen has a clear answer for you:

> So this is what happens, starting with the top-level method (`Button1_Click` for UI / `MyController.Get` for ASP.NET):
>
> 1. The top-level method calls `GetJsonAsync` (within the UI/ASP.NET context).
> 2. `GetJsonAsync` starts the REST request by calling `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` (still within the context).
> 3. `GetStringAsync` returns an uncompleted `Task`, indicating the REST request is not complete.
> 4. `GetJsonAsync` awaits the `Task` returned by `GetStringAsync`. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the `GetJsonAsync` method later. `GetJsonAsync` returns an uncompleted `Task`, indicating that the `GetJsonAsync` method is not complete.
> 5. The top-level method synchronously blocks on the `Task` returned by `GetJsonAsync`. This blocks the context thread.
> 6. ... Eventually, the REST request will complete. This completes the `Task` that was returned by `GetStringAsync`.
> 7. The continuation for `GetJsonAsync` is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
> 8. **Deadlock**. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting for `GetJsonAsync` to complete, and `GetJsonAsync` is waiting for the context to be free so it can complete. For the UI example, the "context" is the UI context; for the ASP.NET example, the "context" is the ASP.NET request context. This type of deadlock can be caused for either "context".

Another link you should read: [*Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/)

Comment: Could it be solved by the OP using `await MyWebService.GetDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` instead of await `MyWebService.GetDataAsync();`?

Answer (score 31):

- **Fact 1:** `GetDataAsync().Result;` will run when the task returned by `GetDataAsync()` completes, in the meantime it blocks the UI thread
- **Fact 2:** The continuation of the await (`return result.ToString()`) is queued to the UI thread for execution
- **Fact 3:** The task returned by `GetDataAsync()` will complete when its queued continuation is run
- **Fact 4:** The queued continuation is never run, because the UI thread is blocked (Fact 1)

### Deadlock!

The deadlock can be broken by provided alternatives to avoid Fact 1 or Fact 2.

- **Fix 1:** Avoid 1,4. Instead of blocking the UI thread, use `var data = await GetDataAsync()`, which allows the UI thread to keep running
- **Fix 2:** Avoid 2,3. Queue the continuation of the await to a different thread that is not blocked, e.g. use `var data = Task.Run(GetDataAsync).Result`, which will post the continuation to the sync context of a threadpool thread. This allows the task returned by  `GetDataAsync()` to complete.

This is explained really well in an [article by Stephen Toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/), about half way down where he uses the example of `DelayAsync()`.

Comment: Regarding, `var data = Task.Run(GetDataAsync).Result`, that's new to me. I always thought the outer `.Result` will be readily available as soon as the first await of `GetDataAsync` is hit, so `data` will always be `default`. Interesting.

Comment: **Fix 2** solved my problem.

Answer (score 30):

I was just fiddling with this issue again in an ASP.NET MVC project. When you want to call `async` methods from a `PartialView`, you're not allowed to make the `PartialView` `async`. You'll get an exception if you do.

You can use the following simple workaround in the scenario where you want to call an `async` method from a sync method:

1. Before the call, clear the `SynchronizationContext`
2. Do the call, there will be no more deadlock here, wait for it to finish
3. Restore the `SynchronizationContext`

Example:

```
public ActionResult DisplayUserInfo(string userName)
{
    // trick to prevent deadlocks of calling async method 
    // and waiting for on a sync UI thread.
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

    //  this is the async call, wait for the result (!)
    var model = _asyncService.GetUserInfo(Username).Result;

    // restore the context
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);

    return PartialView("_UserInfo", model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another main point is that you should not block on Tasks, and use async all the way down to prevent deadlocks. Then it will be all asynchronous not synchronous blocking.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionAsync()
{

    var data = await GetDataAsync();

    return View(data);
}

private async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    // a very simple async method
    var result = await MyWebService.GetDataAsync();
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What if I **want** the main (UI) thread to be blocked until the task finishes? Or in a Console app for example? Let's say I want to use HttpClient, which **only** supports async... How do I use it synchronously *without the risk of deadlock*? This **must** be possible. If WebClient can be used that way (because of having sync methods) and works perfectly, then why couldn't it be done with HttpClient too?

Comment: See answer from Philip Ngan above (i know this was posted after this comment): Queue the continuation of the await to a different thread that is not blocked, e.g. use  var data = Task.Run(GetDataAsync).Result

Comment: @Dexter - re "*What if I want the main (UI) thread to be blocked until the task finishes?*" - do you truly want the UI thread blocked, meaning user can't do anything, can't even cancel - or is it that you don't want to continue the method you are in?  "await" or "Task.ContinueWith" handle the latter case.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve of course I don't want to continue the method. But I simply *cannot* use await because I cannot use async all the way either - HttpClient is invoked in _main_, which of course cannot be async. And then I mentioned doing all this in a Console app - in this case I want exactly the former - I don't want my app to even *be* multi-threaded. Block _everything_.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I came to is to use a `Join` extension method on the task before asking for the result.

The code look's like this:

```
public ActionResult ActionAsync()
{
  var task = GetDataAsync();
  task.Join();
  var data = task.Result;

  return View(data);
}
```

Where the join method is:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static void Join(this Task task)
    {
        var currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            // Make the dispatcher allow this thread to work on other things
            currentDispatcher.Invoke(delegate { }, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not enough into the domain to see the drawbacks of this solution (if any)

Comment: I like this, dispatching actions work great in Redux. I am learning c# and want to know, what's wrong with this and does it work? Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Can it go into a tight loop and use 100% cpu if no other task to run? (In case it will run the empty delegate in a tight loop?)