# Xamarin Gcm Network Manager await httpclient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

I'm using the Gcm Network Manager to schedule tasks, in one of those tasks I need to perform an HTTP request. Until now it was written with HttpWebRequest so nothing was async.

Now I would like to reuse code that is written with HttpClient and is async.

The problem that arrises is that I cannot make the OnRunTask() async as it needs to return an int:

e.g.

```
public override int OnRunTask(TaskParams @params)
{
    var result = await performSync();

    if(result)
    {
        return GcmNetworkManager.ResultSuccess;
    }

    return GcmNetworkManager.ResultReschedule;
}
```

What could I do to be able to reuse async code here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Task.Run inside your `OnRunTask` method like this :

```
 Task.Run( async () =>
        {
             // Do your stuff here
             await asyncTask();
        });
```

You  will no need to have `OnRunTask` async with this technique

Hope it helps

**Edit**

If you need the return value to match the framework / library signature, you can also use .Result

E.g.

```
var result = asyncTask().Result;
...
```

Comment: How about the return value of the task ?

Comment: @RVandersteen You can create a local variable before the task run and after the task run is done return it I think

Comment: @RVandersteen check this post it can maybe help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050836/getting-return-value-from-task-run

Comment: Oh it seems that you can use .Result instead of wait, thanks for the info !

Comment: Edit my answer if you have something more precise to add it can help other people