# How to safely wait for async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've got a method which looks like this:

```
    static async Task<string> GetGooglePage(ProxyInfo proxy)
    {
        using (var m=new MyNetworkClass())
        {
            m.Proxy = proxy;
            return await m.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

now I want to call it from method that is not async, and get the result.

The way I was trying to do it is like this:

```
        foreach (var proxy in proxys)
        {
            try
            {
                GetGooglePage(proxy.ToProxyInfo()).Wait();
            }
            catch
            {}
            lock (Console.Out)
            {
                Console.Write(current++ + "\r");
            }
        }
```

My problem is that sometimes `GetGooglePage(proxy.ToProxyInfo()).Wait();` deadlocks (according to visual studio debugger, there is no stack beyond this call).

I don't want to use async all the way through to `Main()`. How do I correctly call `GetGooglePage` from synchronous code without risking a deadlock?

Comment: I don't see any code which causes deadlock here. How does it happen?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The cause is in the question. `GetGooglePage`'s `return` doesn't get a chance to run until the main thread is available, but it won't become available, because it's waiting for `GetGooglePage` to finish.

Comment: Why are you `lock`ing in your example?  With the way you have your code written, it's running in serial.

Comment: @Matthew the lock for counter I copy pasted from a parallel.ForEach I was running. I was trying to benchmark the code and got tired watching the empty console `GetGooglePage` is not inside the lock

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I run the code, and at some point it stops running. When I break all in VS, it shows current position at `GetGooglePage(proxy.ToProxyInfo()).Wait();`

Comment: @hvd yeah, I think you're right. So how do I call the method correctly and avoid this?

Comment: @ArsenZahray Don't `Wait` on async methods, It can cause deadlock as you've seen. use async/await chain. (Sometimes configuring task with `task.ConfigureAwait(false);` can help if you don't want to interact with UI thread) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock

Comment: @hvd If that is the case it should deadlock always right? or am I missing something?

Comment: @hvd so what you're saying is that Microsoft did not foresee a way to call async method from sync code?

Comment: also, if I mark `Main` as async, I'm getting `an entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Good question. It's possible that `GetAsync` returns synchronously, that depends on how it's implemented. If `GetAsync` happens to return synchronously, so will `GetGooglePage`, and `Wait` will do nothing since the task has already finished.

Comment: @ArsenZahray No, that isn't what I'm saying. Clearly, they did, otherwise there would be no `Wait` method. It's just very easy to use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is not to do this: if you synchronously wait for an async method, there is no reason for the method to be async in the first place. So, what you should do (assuming you really want to or have to make the top level method synchronous) is to make all the methods synchronous.

If you can't do that, then you can prevent the deadlock by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
static async Task<string> GetGooglePage(ProxyInfo proxy)
{
    using (var m=new MyNetworkClass())
    {
        m.Proxy = proxy;
        return await m.GetAsync("http://www.google.com").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

This way, when the method resumes, it won't try resuming on the UI thread, so you won't get the deadlock. If you're using `await` in `GetAsync()` or the methods it calls, you will need to do the same thing there too.

In general, it's a good idea to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere, as long as you don't need to resume of the UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

You're running into a deadlock that I [describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

There is no standard solution for blocking on an `async` method, because there is no solution that works in every situation. The only officially recommended solution is to use `async` all the way. Stephen Toub has a [good summary of workarounds here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx).

One approach is to execute the `async` method in a background thread (via `Task.Run`) and then `Wait` on that. Disadvantages of this approach are: 1) it won't work for `async` methods that require a specific context (e.g., write to an ASP.NET response, or update a UI); 2) changing from a synchronized context to the unsynchronized thread pool context may introduce race conditions; and 3) it burns a thread just waiting for another thread.

Another approach is to execute the `async` method within a nested message loop. Disadvantages of this approach are: 1) the "nested message loop" is different for every platform (WPF vs. WinForms, etc); and 2) nested loops introduce reentrancy issues (which have been responsible for many, many bugs in the Win32 era).