# How to set TaskContinuationOptions using async/await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Can I have all the options like OnlyOnRanToCompletion, OnlyOnCanceled, NotOnFaulted, etc. using async/await? I can't find examples on how to achieve the same results as using Tasks, for instance:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(foo).ContinueWith(bar, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

I'm not sure if simple conditional or exception handling can manage all the continuation behaviors available in explicit Tasks.

Comment: Can you set the bit flags? You should be able to. Tbh, not sure what you are asking

Comment: For the exception handling it's not needed; just use a `try/catch` block and you can write code like you write it like you would in any code virtually anywhere else.  Why would you *want* to use that style instead?  If you want to use something other than the "OnlyOn*" or "NotOn*" options, which do you need and why?

Comment: @natenho, if you really need it, you should be able to implement this behavior with a [custom awaiter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx).

Comment: @Servy I just wanted to correlate features, just doing an exercise to find out the conversion effort and capabilities between raw TPL code and the _elegant_ async/await pattern. Basically, the question is "Can I get the same results with less code?". Because, after all, we know that it's TPL behind the scenes in both cases.

Comment: @natenho You can always replicate what `await` is doing using tasks, but not everything that can be done with explicit tasks can be done using `await`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can I have all the options like OnlyOnRanToCompletion, OnlyOnCanceled, NotOnFaulted, etc. using async/await?

You don't need to.

Instead of copious syntax using bit flags and lambda continuations, `await` supports a very natural `try`/`catch` syntax:

```
try
{
  await foo();
}
catch
{
  bar();
  throw;
}
```

> I'm not sure if simple conditional or exception handling can manage all the continuation behaviors available in explicit Tasks.

They naturally handle `None`, `NotOnCanceled`, `NotOnFaulted`, `NotOnRanToCompletion`, `OnlyOnCanceled`, `OnlyOnFaulted`, and `OnlyOnRanToCompletion`. Most of the other flags only make sense for parallel tasks, not asynchronous tasks. E.g., `AttachedToParent`, `HideScheduler`, and `PreferFairness` don't make sense in the `async` world; `DenyChildAttach`, `LazyCancellation`, and `ExecuteSynchronously` should *always* be specified in the `async` world; and `LongRunning` *never* should be.

Comment: Simple exception handling was my first approach for the NotOn* and is good to confirm that's ok. I'll have to take a closer look at the other flags to review the last part of your sentence ;)

Comment: I got here when I ran into a situation that I needed to specify the 
`HideScheduler` flag, and I couldn't. The scenario: an async method is called from a
GUI thread, which GUI thread is blocked until the end of the async call.
This results in a deadlock because the continuation is posted back to the
(waiting & blocked) GUI thread. HideScheduler would save the day.


Work-around: `new Task({async call},TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler).Start()`
and wait for this temporary task.

Comment: I know that usually it's an ill design to have the GUI thread blocked during an async call, but this was a special program: mainly headless operations (imagine a backup task) with GUI used during development only to provide feedback -- invisible/disabled/blocked in production environment.

Comment: I don't think `HideScheduler` does what you think it does (it doesn't do anything unless you're actually executing the task on a task scheduler). There are better options. Option 1) Make your UI asynchronous. Option 2) Create the task using `Task.Run`. Option 3) Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid the deadlock.

Comment: @Stephen: you're right, I also realized it meanwhile. +1 for `ConfigureAwait()`,
what I found by reading 
[stackoverflow.com/a/15022170](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15022170)
and [Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Async/await was not made to replace TPL all together, but to supplement it by making simple operations cleaner.
If you still need extra configuration, you'll have to stick to tasks, or you could try implementing a custom awaiter with this behavior.