# How to render a partial view asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Can a partial view be rendered asynchronously?

I have a partial view that needs to render blog posts. The blog posts are returned asynchronously.

In my `_Layout` file I render my partial footer `_Footer`. In `_Footer` I have the following markup:

```
@Html.Action("FooterLatestBlogPosts", "Common")
```

So in my `Common` controller I have the following action method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FooterLatestBlogPosts()
{
     List<ArticleDTO> articleDTOs = await articleTask.GetAllAsync();

     return PartialView(articleDTOs);
}
```

In my `FooterLatestBlogPosts` partial view I have the following:

```
@model List<MyProject.Application.DTO.ArticleDTO>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
     <ul class="list-unstyled">
          @foreach (var articleDTO in Model)
          {
               <li>@articleDTO.Title</li>
          }
     </ul>
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'
```

Should I rather just create a synchronous mthod to bring back my data?

Comment: Perhaps that should be @Html.Partial("FooterLatestBlogPosts", "Common") instead.

Comment: @buffjape I've tried that as well and get the following error. Just remember that `FooterLatestBlogPosts` is not under shared, but is an action method and view in my `Common` controller: `The partial view 'FooterLatestBlogPosts' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations`

Comment: OK, ignore me and check out other questions e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072720/async-partialview-causes-httpserverutility-execute-blocked-exception

Comment: It is not the same using @Html.Partial() instead of @Html.Action(). Action call a Controller/Method.. can not call a Partial() if you need to apply some logic and recolect some data...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went with the answer in the post that @buffjape suggested:

[Async PartialView causes "HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked..." exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072720/async-partialview-causes-httpserverutility-execute-blocked-exception)

I changed my methods all to synchronous.

Answer (score 47):

First of all you need to use `Html.Partial` as suggested by @buffjape. If your partial view is not in `Shared` folder you need to specify the path to the view

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/FooterLatestBlogPosts", yourModel)`

However in this case your view is still loaded synchronously. To load it in async way you need to load it via jQuery. Article [Improve perceived performance of ASP.NET MVC websites with asynchronous partial views](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/) gives a very good description on how to achieve it.

Also replace your `Html.Render` with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#yourContainer").load('@Url.Action("FooterLatestBlogPosts", "Common")')
});
```

Comment: I went with @buffjape post that he suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult FooterLatestBlogPosts()
{
     List<ArticleDTO> articleDTOs = articleTask.GetAllAsync().Result;

     return PartialView(articleDTOs);
}
```

this will work in your case