# async Dynamic partial view using action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, renderpartial

System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'
InvalidOperationException: HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.
[my partail view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjFhi.png)[my render controller methode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYtvB.png)
[My get method that is async to call api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhbNr.png)

i tried to access render partial view but fails i want dynamic  async partial view using @html.Action or any other

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what's the version of your project? Asp.net mvc or Asp.net core? If your project is not asp.net core, Please remove asp.net core tag.  Please refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072720/async-partialview-causes-httpserverutility-execute-blocked-exception) in SO.