# Task.Delay never completing

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, delay

The following code will freeze forever.

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomethingAsync().Wait();
    // Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
}
```

If I switch the call to `DoSomethingAsync` with the commented out code, it behaves as expected. I suspect that somehow the nested awaits are causing a deadlock, but I'm not sure why, or how to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An async/await example that causes a deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming `Button_Click` runs in the `GUI` thread you have a deadlock on your hands.

When you use `Wait` on a task you are synchronously blocking the thread until the task ends, but the task will never end because the continuation (the completion of `Task.Delay(2000);`) must run on the GUI thread as well (which is blocked on `Wait).`

You have several solutions. Either use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to not capture the GUI thread's SynchronizationContext:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Or (which I recommend) use an `async void` event handler (which is the only appropriate place for an `async void` method):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}

public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Took me almost 3h to find the cause of a gui-thread-async-await bug... i'd give you two ups if i could!