# Entity framework ToListAsync block ui at first execution

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a **next view model:**

```
public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; private set; }

    private IEnumerable<Databases.Main.Models.Robot> _testCollection;
    public IEnumerable<Databases.Main.Models.Robot> TestCollection
    {
        get { return _testCollection; }
        private set
        {
            _testCollection = value;
            var handler = Volatile.Read(ref PropertyChanged);
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestCollection"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        TestCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(Test);
    }

    private async Task Test()
    {
        using (var context = new AtonMainDbContext())
        {
            TestCollection = await context.Set<Databases.Main.Models.Robot>().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

and **next xaml:**

```
            <Button Content="Refresh"
                    Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

When i execute TestCommand, UI freeze at first execution for a few seconds. I don't like it.
But if i don't use ToListAsync and just wrap ToList method with Task, that everything works fine and UI don't freeze.

```
    private async Task Test()
    {
        using (var context = new AtonMainDbContext())
        {
            TestCollection = await Task.Run(() => context.Set<Databases.Main.Models.Robot>().ToList());
        }
    }
```

Why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Result` or `Wait` somewhere.

That's a [classic ASP.NET deadlock.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock) Don't block. The `Task.Run` is a workaround because it removes the synchronization context in its body.