# Configured SD card path in emulator is null - Windows Phone 8.1 (runtime)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, removable-storage

I am very much confused with WP 8.1 (runtime) SD card access. I am trying to create a folder in WP 8.1 (Runtime) Sd Card, but unable to do so. I am following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx) tutorial to access sd card in WinRT. I need SD card access in order to store my App's backup & log folders. By following [this](https://monkeyweekend.wordpress.com/2014/12/09/write-a-file-to-the-sd-card-on-windows-phone-8-1/) tutorial I configured sd card path in emulator and I am using below code to access that path.

```
 private async Task<string> AsyncExternalStoragePath()
 {
   // Get the logical root folder for all external storage devices.
   Windows.Storage.StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;

   // Get the first child folder, which represents the SD card.
   StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)).FirstOrDefault();


 }
```

`externalDevices.Path` returns empty string instead of returning the path which I configured. I enabled `RemovableStorage` under `Capabilities` and added `FileTypeAssociations`. But honestly this `FileTypeAssociations` are very much confusing to me. I read many articles, but I am not yet clarified fully.

Basically I want two folders and one file under my app name folder.

```
AppnameFolder -> BackupFolder, LogFolder, Infile
```

Under each folder

```
Backup -> To keep last five backup files (.db)
Log -> To create log files per day basis (.txt)
inifile -> To enable logging
```

If I know how to create a custom folder (app name folder) in sd card, I would create sub-folders (backup, log) easily. But right now I am stuck in getting the root path.

**Edit**: Deadlock problem got solved by adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` in async call as suggested in comment, but sdcard path is still null, How can I get path and create folder there?

Comment: do you use `Task.Result` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, in the calling function I am using Task.Result

Comment: possible duplicate of [An async/await example that causes a deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **"externalDevices"** you are querying all the storage devices in your phone.
Then trying to find its path.

You should find the path of the *root folder* of the sdcard, not the path of the sdcard itself.

**"sdCard.path"** will work.

***Edit after Subha's comment***:
Assuming the *Removable Storage* is declared in appxmanifest and the emulator has the emulated sdcard inserted (as described is the tutorials; did Storage Sense give a popup?) the following should work.
Note that I am not using task.

```
StorageFolder sdcard;

public async void read_sdcard_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sdcard = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
}

private void some_other_method()
{
    textbox.Text = sdcard.path;
}
```

Comment: I have configured sd card path in emulator, but it returns sdCard as null, also how to get root folder of the sdcard?

Comment: Edited my answer. Can you check/try this?

Comment: My code is same as yours, instead of directly accessing RemovableDevices.GetFolderAsync(), I am using externalDevices variable, that's it right? I added ConfigureAwait to fix deadlock.

Comment: Using *externalDevices* should not be a problem. (Personally I don't use extra variables if not really needed.) The only difference in our code is the "run as task bit". Should not be problem though.

Comment: Just did some testing. Reverted the emulator to the default checkpoint (so without the sdcard), started my app and it gave a null-reference to the sdcard (as you described in your post). Inserted the sdcard (StorageSense app popped up "_new sdcard found_") and ran my app again. Now the sdcard is found and the folders and files can be queried. Double check if StorageSense can actually detect the sdcard. It looks like a problem with the sdcard in the emulator rather the code in your app.