# Asyc method using await Task.Run() never "completes"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a method that is defined as

```
public async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
{
   DoSomeStuff();
   await Task.Run(() => {
     DoSomeSyncStuff();
     DoSomeOtherSyncStuff();
   });
   var someDebugVariable = "someDebugValue";
}
```

The method itself does exactly what it is supposed to do and everything runs fine. Yet ... it looks like the "outer" async `Task` never completes.

Example: When I call it like this

```
public void CallerMethod()
{
   Task t = SomeAsyncMethod();
   t.Wait();
}
```

the `t.Wait()` never completes. Furthermore: if I place a breakpoint at the assignment of `someDebugVariable` it never gets hit.

I might add that `DoSomeSyncStuff` and `DoSomeOtherSyncStuff` really do what they are supposed to and debugging through them tells me that they both complete.

To prove my point I modified my method like this, and the results are still the same.

```
public async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
{
   DoSomeStuff();
   await Task.Run(() => {
     /*
     DoSomeSyncStuff();
     DoSomeOtherSyncStuff();
     */
     var a = 2; var b = 3; var c = a + b;
   });
   var someDebugVariable = "someDebugValue";
}
```

EDIT

I have tried removing everything but the `await Task.Run` and it does not change anything. It still does not complete.

The application is a WPF application. The caller thread is the UI thread.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you invoke it in single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: In your example, the task is never actually started, so `Wait` will never be called.

Comment: If the task really would never be started, the anonymous method I passed would not start either, and therefore I would not be able to debug it, but I am. The program steps into it.

Comment: @PetSerAl: I do not use any `SynchronizationContext`. The invokation is just a test-method I wrote to check if the task really does not complete.

Comment: Can you comment DoSomeStuff(); in your last test code to ensure that problem is not in in this function?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Is the code run on a UI thread or an ASP Request context thread?

Comment: Is it possible that `var someDebugVariable = "someDebugValue";` maybe optimized out by the compiler? Don't know if this should happen in debug version/mode, too. You might try to output `someDebugVariable` on the next line.

Comment: It is not optimized out by the compiler. I'm pretty sure the problem is a deadlock since Task.Run spawns a new thread that is unable to return control to the blocked main (UI or ASP) thread. Need more info to be sure though

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html this should be relevant for you

Comment: @Hemisphera WPF UI thread use `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`, so you are actually use some `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Are there any blocking calls used in your sync methods called in your task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An async/await example that causes a deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock)

Comment: @PetSerEl: What I meant is that I never *explicitly* used one and never thought about it. The problem infact is a deadlock. I now need to find out where and why exactly but Steve's anwser solved my problem.

Comment: @kai My sync methods make SQL-Server calls.

Comment: That would explain it. I take it these are not made via a true asynchronous API?

Comment: @kai: yes they do. But the actual `System.Data.SqlClient` calls are so deep down, hidden in other libraries (not all mine) and whatnot that I cannot always use true async/await. A real pity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The t.Wait() call is causing a deadlock, and also makes the async call entirely pointless. I believe if you change the code to

```
await Task.Run(() => {
// ...
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You can fix the deadlock and let the code proceed, but you should really get rid of the t.Wait() call. Anything that needs to be done with the results of the sync function calls should be done after the awaited task, not after the call of the async function.

More in depth:
task.Wait() will block all execution on the main thread while the task is running. When the await task completes, it tries to marshall back to the main thread, but the main thread is blocked! Since A is waiting for B, and B is waiting for A, you get a deadlock.

See: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Actually the `t.Wait` is just testing code. The caller is not async and I need to execute an async-method and read it's result and return it. I did not think about deadlocks. Will try to check that ...

Comment: @serhiyb See the source I posted. He used the term deadlock, so I did as well. Main thread is waiting for task to complete, task is waiting for main thread. Deadlock.

Comment: This solved my problem. Now I just need to find the root of evil (= deadlock) and find out who blocks whom.

Comment: @Hemisphera He already told you. The `await` is waiting for the UI thread to become free before it completes and the `.Wait()` is blocking the UI thread till the `await` completes. You have two things waiting for the other to finish before they stop waiting.

Comment: Dear Lord in heaven ... .ConfigureAwait(false) saved the day for me too. I had two awaits and the 2nd was never resolving/completing - this fixed it! Thanks.

Comment: The old solutions are sometimes still the best. Hello from the future!