# Why does this async/await code NOT cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have found the following example in Jon Skeet's "C# in depth. 3rd edition":

```
static async Task<int> GetPageLengthAsync(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Task<string> fetchTextTask = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        int length = (await fetchTextTask).Length;
        return length;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Task<int> lengthTask = GetPageLengthAsync("http://csharpindepth.com");
    Console.WriteLine(lengthTask.Result);
}
```

I expected that this code would deadlock, but it does not.

As I see it, it works this way:

1. `Main` method calls `GetPageLengthAsync` synchronously within the main thread.
2. `GetPageLengthAsync` makes an asynchronous request and immediately returns `Task<int>` to `Main` saying "wait for a while, I will return you an int in a second".
3. `Main` continues execution and stumbles upon `lengthTask.Result` which causes the main thread to block and wait for `lengthTask` to finish its work.
4. `GetStringAsync` completes and waits for main thread to become available to execute `Length` and start continuation.

But it seems like I misunderstand something. Why doesn't this code deadlock?

The code in [this StackOverflow question about await/async deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock) seems to do the same, but deadlocks.

Comment: for a deadlock you need two asynchronous activities competing for a shared resource. I don't understand why you think that is the case here.

Comment: @Jodrell it's a common gotcha in GUI/ASP.NET applications - .Result blocks the UI thread, so `await` can't return to the original synchronization context. Same for ASP.NET. Console and .NET Core applications, including ASP.NET Core have no sync context

Comment: @juharr the OP asked a valid question. You *can* get into deadlocks if you try this code in a WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`await` returns to the original synchronization context, whether that is the UI thread (in desktop UI applications) or the request context in ASP.NET (not core).

In a GUI application, you'd have a deadlock because the UI thread was locked by `.Result`. `await` would await forever for this call to finish.

Console applications and ASP.NET Core have no synchronization context, so calling `.Result` won't cause a deadlock.

**PS for VS 15.3:**

[Visual Studio 2017 15.3 Preview 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes) (gasp) allows asynchronous main applications. With it, You can write :

```
public static Task Main()
{
    var length = await GetPageLengthAsync("http://csharpindepth.com");
    Console.WriteLine(length);
}
```

Comment: anytime you use an STA I guess. RE VS2017 15.3 Preview 2, at last! Looks interesting.

Comment: @Jodrell It's not about the STA, the threadpool threads are MTA by design. It's about the way the synchronization context is implemented in different platforms. ASP.NET Core just doesn't use a request context like ASP.NET. Console applications don't need a synchronization context to begin with

Comment: @Jodrell check Stephen Cleary's [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) for more pointers