# Exceptions handling does not work in asp.net controller for async/await call

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I wonder why exception handling behaves differently in asp.net and console for async/await calls. Consider this method:

```
        private static async Task Test()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    throw new Exception("Test Exception");
                });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Catch does not hit in ASP.NET non-async controller like this working under IIS, neither in Test() nor in TestAction():

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult TestAction()
    {
        try
        {
            Test().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
     }
```

Instead http request hangs. Same Console code or WindowsForms code work fine hitting catch in both places:

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        try
        {
            Test().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This code work fine though (catch is called) in asp.net controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult TestAction()
{
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Test Exception");
            }).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Deadlock?  Instead of calling `.Wait()`, make `TestAction()` also `async` and `await` the method.  That's generally the correct approach anyway, so might as well start there.

Comment: right, async Controller works fine if I put `await Test()` instead of `Test().Wait()` in an action method, but still want to know why it does not work for synchronous version

Comment: Have you tried adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your `await Task.Run...` and seeing if it still happens? That's usually the first thing to try when running into a deadlock involving `async`/`await`.

Comment: @YMC: This looks helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock

Comment: Using `.Wait()` on a task is something to be avoided unless you absolutely know what you're doing. See [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: @kanders84152, `await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("Test Exception"); }).ConfigureAwait(false);` does the trick and exception starts catching properly by calling context. Though I still do not totally understand why is a discrepancy here

Comment: @YMC `TestAction()` calls `Test()` which runs synchronously until `Task.Run...`. Then `await` relinquishes the current thread. The `Wait()` in the `TestAction()` now takes that thread and blocks it until the task finishes. Meanwhile, the task throws and is done. Control should return to the line after the `await`, but it can't, because it wants to return control to the thread that it was called from, which is blocked. Ergo, deadlock. `ConfigureAwait(false)` tells it that it is ok to return control on a different thread than the original one, thus allowing `TestAction()` to finish.

Comment: @kanders84152 alright, now it makes sense for me, though not sure then how one-thread console and Windows application happened to work fine. Nevertheless, you're free to post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestAction()` calls `Test()` which runs synchronously until `Task.Run....` Then `await` relinquishes the current thread. The `Wait()` in the `TestAction()` now takes that thread and blocks it until the task finishes. Meanwhile, the task throws and is done. Control should return to the line after the `await`, but it can't, because it wants to return control to the thread that it was called from, which is blocked. Ergo, deadlock. `ConfigureAwait(false)` tells it that it is ok to return control on a different thread than the original one, thus allowing `TestAction()` to finish.

It works fine in console applications because they don't have a `SynchronizationContext` that insists on returning control to the original thread. WPF and asp.net have that custom synchronization context because there are changes that have to be made from the calling thread.