# Calling HttpClient asynchronously to get the HttpResponseMessage via ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

I am actually trying to fetch data through a URL using the **HTTPClient** class. I am calling via ajax call. However, when the response is fetched it gets back into running mode from debugging mode and nothing happens. No response is retrieved. Below is the code:

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../../Services/AService.asmx/GetCompanyInformation",
        data: { id: JSON.stringify(id) },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async:true,
        success: function (res) {
            var options = JSON.parse(res.d);                   

        },
        error: function (errormsg) {
            $(".dropdown_SubDomainLoading").hide();
            toastr.options.timeOut = 7000;
            toastr.options.closeButton = true;
            toastr.error('Something Went Wrong');
        }
    });
```

**WebMethod Call**

```
public static string CompanyDetails;

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string GetCompanyInformation(string id)
    {
        string authorizationKey = "Bearer 5cae498ef11f128363c1fbb2761bbab40ac0e2e5";
        string url = string.Empty;
        url = GetCompanyDetailsForApps(id);
        RunAsync(url).Wait();
        return CompanyDetails;
    }

 static async Task RunAsync(string Url)
    {
        string authorizationKey = "Bearer 5cae498ef11f128363c1fbb2761bbab40ac0e2e5";
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationKey);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //UrlMetricsResponse mozResonse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UrlMetricsResponse>(content);
                    dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
                    CompanyDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynObj);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR :" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

As soon as the **client.GetAsync()** function is called, it comes back to run mode and nothing is fetched. Am I doing something wrong. How can i retrieve the response via the url?

Comment: Most probably the call to client.GetAsync(Url) failed and it didn't go into the if block, so your CompanyDetails object is empty or null and that is returned to the client. If you set a break point exactly at the if statement, you should be able to see whats happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An async/await example that causes a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by `[WebMethod]`, I'm guessing you are maintaining a *very* old ASP.NET application. The problem here is incompatible libraries. Old ASP.NET does not support async/await semantics, and `HttpClient` does not support synchronous HTTP operations.

Your best option is to upgrade the application to something more modern that supports async controllers, such as ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET Core. This way you won't have to block threads on HTTP calls. But if this is not an option, you need swap out HttpClient for a library that actually *supports* synchronous/blocking HTTP. Have a look at [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class) or RestSharp. If you continue to use HttpClient and there are `.Result` or `.Wait()` calls *anywhere* on the call stack, you're not only blocking but you are [inviting deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

I can't stress this enough: **HttpClient does not support synchronous HTTP**, so if you can't switch to a more modern web framework, you must switch to an older HTTP library.

Comment: I tried the WebRequest part. But it is actually throwing error when the url is not correct rather that informing. While using HttpClient, it ask for **IsStatusCodeSucceeded**. However, with WebRequest, it plays with Statuscode. If found, it will pass else if will throw an exception. How can we overcome this situation in WebRequest?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Maybe this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/handling-errors

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I changed the `client.GetAsync()` to `client.GetAsync().Result` it worked.

Comment: Please don't do that. It may have worked in your testing, but once you start adding concurrent users, you're eventually going to find yourself in deadlock hell.

Comment: than what should I use.. as I am actually confused.

Comment: WebRequest or RestSharp. See my answer for details.