# await Task.WhenAll() appears to be deadlocking

Tags: c#, async-await, task

In the following code, a deadlock happens on the `Task.WhenAll` line:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetLdapEntries_ReturnsLdapEntries()
{
    var ldapEntries = _fixture.CreateMany<LdapEntryDto>(2).ToList();
    var creationTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var led in ldapEntries)
    {
        var task = _attributesServiceClient.CreateLdapEntry(led);
        creationTasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(creationTasks); // <- deadlock here

    var result = await _ldapAccess.GetLdapEntries();

    result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(ldapEntries);
}

public async Task<LdapEntryDto> CreateLdapEntry(LdapEntryDto ldapEntryDto)
{
    using (var creationResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<LdapEntryDto>("", ldapEntryDto))
    {
        if (creationResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            return await creationResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<LdapEntryDto>();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The xUnit test attempts to create test data asynchronously by calling an asynchronous method that itself `await`s  a response from a web service. `_httpClient` is a real `HttpClient` created off an in-memory [`TestServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver?view=aspnetcore-2.2) via `TestServer.CreateClient()`.

When setting a breakpoint on the `using line` in the `CreateLdapEntry` method, it is hit twice. A breakpoint on the status code check is never hit. When breaking on `Task.WhenAll()` and inspecting `creationTasks`, both tasks are in state `WaitingForActivation`:

```
creationTasks
Count = 2
    [0]: Id = 32, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
    [1]: Id = 33, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

When not using `Task.WhenAll()` but instead awaiting each task individually, no deadlock occurs:

```
foreach (var led in ldapEntries)
{
    await _attributesServiceClient.CreateLdapEntry(led);
}
```

I am aware that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15021304/3129340) has been asked and answered, however the code examples there make use of `.Result`, not of `await Task.WhenAll()`.

I'd like to understand why that deadlock is occuring when using `Task.WhenAll()`.

EDIT: Added Call Stack of locked threads

```
Not Flagged     3992    11  Worker Thread   Worker Thread   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke
                        [Managed to Native Transition]
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)
                        ShibbolethAttributes.Service.dll!RoleManager.Service.Middleware.ApiKeyHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 38
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Startd__7>(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7 stateMachine)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.Context context)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.ApplicationWrapper.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.Context context)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.HttpContextBuilder.SendAsync.AnonymousMethod__0()
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Startc__DisplayClass10_0.b__0>d stateMachine)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.HttpContextBuilder.SendAsync.AnonymousMethod__0()
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Not Flagged     1496    10  Worker Thread   Worker Thread   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)
                        ShibbolethAttributes.Service.dll!RoleManager.Service.Middleware.ApiKeyHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 38
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Startd__7>(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7 stateMachine)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.Context context)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.ApplicationWrapper.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.Context context)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.HttpContextBuilder.SendAsync.AnonymousMethod__0()
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Startc__DisplayClass10_0.b__0>d stateMachine)
                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.HttpContextBuilder.SendAsync.AnonymousMethod__0()
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)
                        System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: Is `buildException` ever hit? If so, please post the code

Comment: It would be helpful to include all relevant code (like `buildException`).  [Also I would recommend appending Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: `I'd like to understand why that deadlock is occuring when using Task.WhenAll().` Looks like you have a context contention between the tasks that are executing at the same time. In your working code each task processes on it's own so no race conditions can occur there between tasks.

Comment: `buildException` is never hit, when instead of `throw`ing I just `return null`, nothing changes. Changed the code in question accordingly.

Comment: What data type is `_httpClient`? Is it an actual `HttpClient`, or a mock?

Comment: @canton7 It's an actual `HttpClient`, obtained via `TestServer.CreateClient()`, `TestServer` being an in-memory version of a web service.

Comment: OK, what does the "Threads" window show? I wonder whether maybe your `TestService` isn't safe to two queries happening at the same time. What happens if you replace your call to `_httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` with something else which doesn't try and talk to a remote server, such as `await Task.Delay(100); return new ....`.

Comment: Apparently, that's it - replacing the whole method with `await Task.Delay(100); return null;` removed the deadlock. Sadly I don't know how to interprete the threads window.

Comment: Re the threads-window, just double-click on all threads and see what they're doing. Most won't be doing anything, but you'll have at least one that's stuck on *something* in your code, I suspect (or your code is somewhere in the stack trace). Then you can go through the "Call Stack" window and see how it ended up where it is.

Comment: `TestServer being an in-memory version of a web service` <= is it thread safe? What is the implementation of this service?

Comment: @Igor ASP .Net Core Test Server Class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver?view=aspnetcore-2.2 I would guess apparently, it is not thread safe.

Comment: Did you try appending `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the 2 awaitable async calls in method `CreateLdapEntry`?

Comment: Huh, interesting. Seeing where the thread is stuck will be crucial to figuring out what's going on.

Comment: @Igor I did, without success. @canton7 When breaking on `Task.WhenAll()`, a thread seems stuck on `await _next.Invoke(context);` of some middleware, or rather on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about asp.net core to know why that might have deadlocked. If I could reproduce it I might be able to have a dig around and see if I could spot something, but sadly that looks like a reasonable amount of effort. Something that's worth trying though: maybe a different `HttpClient` for each request?

Comment: I found the underlying error, I think. The web server opens a ldap connection, apparently I have some concurrency issues there. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice find. Odd about the ldap connection considering it should be a fake web server call (or maybe this connection is somewhere else in the code?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Conclusion summarised from the comments, for any future viewers).

You're not blocking anywhere, so the only possible explanation I can think of is that at least one of the requests isn't completing.

(If you were synchronously waiting for a `Task` to complete then I could well expect a deadlock, since you're not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but since you only ever `await` your Tasks, I pretty sure this isn't the cause).

Given that your requests complete successfully when they're run individually, this implies that there's some concurrency issue when multiple requests are run in parallel, possibly to do with whatever `_httpClient` is, or to do with the server that requests are being made against (if they're running against a real server).

Given that your Task list doesn't show anything interesting, I'm inclined to think that one of the requests has synchronously blocked the thread that called into it.

Just see whether one of the requests has synchronously blocked. Open the Threads window, and double-click each thread in turn. Most won't be doing anything, but at least one might be running your code, or running a method called from your code. Look at the call stack to try and find out what's going on. You can double-click entries in the call stack to inspect variables in scope at each point.