# Does calling HttpClient.PostAsync().Result still cause an async scheduling?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-core-3.1

### Background

I have an issue where I am hitting my method with very high load.  The load is so high that it seems that it is causing resuming of `await` to have scheduling issues.

Basically, I was calling `await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);`.  But because I was hitting it so fast (multiple threads), I eventually got very long wait times on the client (the service was still responding very fast).  From what I can see, this wait time was due to stress of getting 10s of thousands of resuming `awaits` scheduled on a thread.

### Question

If I call `httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result` will that still result in a scheduled resuming of the remaining code, or will it really execute synchronously?

Comment: TL;DR; - you'll use roughly twice as many threads that way. What happens discussed many times and you likely can find better explanations than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock (the only difference between core and regular asp.net is core one will not deadlock as it no longer uses synchronization context, but otherwise is the same).

Comment: Accessing .Result is a really really bad idea; that blocks a pool thread that wasn't expecting to be blocked - which can cause thread-pool starvation

Comment: @MarcGravell - If I use `await` I find that my `Parallel.ForEach` loop runs way past the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of 10 that I am trying to enforce.  It seems that when the `await` is hit, it makes the parallel loop think that the thread is done, and it starts another.  That is how I get to overwhelming the scheduler (and other resource issues).  I want only 10 requests running at a time, but when I use await, I get way more than that.  This has lead me to the awkward conclusion that I WANT it to block, so that I only ever get 10 running at a time.

Comment: @Vaccano yes, that's because Parallel.ForEach is using Action, which means that your `async` lambda is actually `async void`, which is *really really bad* (and will mean, among other things, that max-dop is not respected, but honestly: that's just the tip of the iceberg for reasons to never ever use `async void` outside of an event-handler). Ironically, the TPL (Parallel.ForEach) doesn't always play nicely with `async`/`await`, because it predates them. Or perhaps not ironic: parallelism and async are related but separate concepts

Comment: It sounds like what you want can be solved with something like this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/