# FluentFtp async methods not workng

Tags: c#, fluentftp

I am downloading a file from an ftp usin FLuentFtp. If I call the synchroneous methods:

```
client.Connect();

var status = client.DownloadFile(localPath, ftpPath);
```

then it works but the asynchroneous versions namely:

```
await client.ConnectAsync();

FtpStatus status = client.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, ftpPath).Result;
```

both don't work. Neither throw an exception but they don't complete within 2 minutes where the synchroneous versions take 2 seconds.

Could it be that there isn't a thread available to run these methods, and if so how can I check this.

The TaskState is WaitingForActivation if that helps narrow things down.

Comment: Why don't you await `DownloadFileAsync`? Why do you call `Result` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have a [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock) in line:

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, ftpPath).Result;
```

You should call it with await:

```
FtpStatus status = await client.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, ftpPath);
```

Comment: Ok fair point but it doesn't even reach that line when connect is called asynchroneously. I also disagree that it should deadlock but block the thread I agree with.

Comment: Actually I tried the solution in the question you linked and it fixed my problem. I can't say Ifully understand why but it is now working