# Why is SaveChangesAsync.Wait not responding in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am using Blazor.
Why does the SaveChangesAsync.Wait() method in the code below return no response?

It reflects in the database, the update is done, but it waits forever. Why?

*I don't want to use the synchronous SaveChanges() method. I want to know the cause of this problem.*

```cs
private void Run()
{
    try
    {
        var id = Guid.Parse("5C7B0B3D-08FA-406D-ABCA-18EE33321B55");

        var data = DbContext.Set<MyModel>().AsTracking(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll)
                  .Single(x => x.Id == id);

        data.UpdateDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }
    finally
    {
        DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None)
        .Wait(CancellationToken.None); // <-- waiting here forever. Why?
    }
}
```

where called:

```cs
private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    Run();

    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("swalInfo", null, "Demo");
}
```

razor.cs:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@dto" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">...
```

Comment: Don't call `SaveChangesAsync` unless you're in an `async` method, and **never** use `.Wait()` or `.Result` on an incomplete `Task`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock - change your code to use `dbContext.SaveChanges();` - not the async version.

Comment: Why are you not calling SaveChanges when you are not awaiting the Task returned by Async call

Comment: _"but it waits forever. Why?"_ - because your code is deadlocking because you're using `.Wait()` when you're not meant to.

Comment: The problem is that Task continuation can not contact the calling context thread to continue because context thread is already blocked by synchronously waiting for Task completion

Comment: You may want to read about the [async-await pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model) in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But it works while in BackgroundService. Shouldn't it have the same reaction here?

Comment: Related: [An async/await example that causes a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock).

Comment: It works in a background service because that's probably not running on the UI thread.  It still blocks that thread. [Polite] If you don't understand that you're blocking threads, then you're out of your depth.  Take the advice provided.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule is "Async All The Way" and "Keep it Simple".  It's `async` in method declarations and `await` in calls. Unless you're an Async specialist, anything else is guesswork and voodoo.

Your `Run` should look something like this.

See this on how to use a DBContext factory - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```cs
private async ValueTask RunAsync()
{
        // You should be using a DbContextFctory here

        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();

        var id = Guid.Parse("5C7B0B3D-08FA-406D-ABCA-18EE33321B55");

        var data = await dbContext.Set<MyModel>().AsTracking(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll)
                  .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

        if(data is not null)
        {
            data.UpdateDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            var result = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            if(result == 1)
            {
                // onbly one update so all ok
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then :

```cs
private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    await RunAsync();

    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("swalInfo", null, "Demo");
}
```